# Android API 21 - footer view IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, listview, footer

I have a ListView in my app that use a footerView. My code works well on every devices except those with API 21 : i got an IndexOutOfBoundsException.
My ListView contains a classment, and this classement can be sorted differently via a spinner. My app crash every time that i change the order of my classment for the second time.

This is my code in onCreate :

```
    //ListView
    classement_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.classement_listview);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    footer_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.classement_listview_footer, null);
    classement_listview.addFooterView(footer_view);
    classementAdapter = new ClassementAdapter();
    classement_listview.setAdapter(classementAdapter);

    //Spinner
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_sort_by);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.classement_sort_by_entries, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

This is what i do in onItemSelected (the spinner's listener)

```
    classement_listview.removeFooterView(footer_view);
    classementAdapter.clearUsers();
    classement_viewflipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            classementService.getClassement(ClassementActivity.this, typeClassement, countNbusers);
        }
    }).start();
```

And here is the method who update the ListView :

```
@Override
public void onClassementReceived(Classement classement) {
    if (classement == null) {
        classement_viewflipper.setDisplayedChild(2);
        return;
    }
    classement_viewflipper.setDisplayedChild(1);

    List<User> users = classement.getUsers();
    classementAdapter.addUsers(users);
    this.countNbusers += users.size();
    if (countNbusers >= classement.getNbMaxUsers()) {
        if (classement_listview.getFooterViewsCount() == 0)
            classement_listview.addFooterView(footer_view);
    } else
        classement_listview.removeFooterView(footer_view);

    classementAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And this is the error :

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
        at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3307)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15117)
        ... (etc) ...
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: At which line do you get the exception?

Comment: I have no idea, the exception's stacktrace doesn't show any line of my code. The only way i found to escape this exception is to comment all lines with my footer_view.

Comment: I get excatly the same, the exception appear when removing the footer view (classement_listview.removeFooterView(footer_view);) did you find a way to correct it?

Comment: Happens to me too, same on android 4.4, 5 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and by doing some tests I realized that this happens because I have two consecutive invokations to `list.removeFooterView(mFooterView)`, just like you have.

First time I call `removeFooterView` in my onResponse method (onClassmentReceived in your case) and then I call it again inside the ScrollListener.onScroll() method, that I use to know when to load next page of data.

I'm working to better understand why, but deleting the invokation in the onScroll() method, everything works fine on all of my testing devices. 
Please let me know if this works for you too so maybe we can understand something more! :)